# mysql not equal is not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a huge problem, I don't what is going on. This is my

**`table1`**

```
+-----+-----------------------+--------------+
| id  | invoice_number | invoice_date |
+-----+-----------------------+--------------+
|  12 | 12536801244    | 2009-09-23   |
|  38 | 12585302890    | 2009-11-18   |
|  37 | 12584309829    | 2009-11-16   |
| 123 | 12627605146    | 2010-01-06   |
| 191 | 12663105176    | 2010-02-16   |
+-----+-----------------------+--------------+
```

and this is my second

**`table2`**

```
+-----+-----------------------+--------------+
| id  | invoice_number | invoice_date |
+-----+-----------------------+--------------+
|  12 | 1t657801244    | 2009-09-23   |
|  20 | 12585302890    | 2009-11-18   |
|  37 | 1ss58430982    | 2009-11-16   |
| 103 | 12627605146    | 2010-01-06   |
| 121 | 12346310517    | 2010-02-16   |
+-----+-----------------------+--------------+
```

What I want is, I have get all invoice_numbers that are not in **`table2`**

This is my SQL query.

```
select t2.invoice_number FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.invoice_number != t1.inovice_number;
```

But I get different result. Any body what is wrong with SQL code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Performance wise you can use Left Join or Not EXIST

**Try with Left Join**

```
Select t2.invoice_number 
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON 
          t2.invoice_number = t1.inovice_number AND
          t2.invoice_number IS NULL;
```

**Try With Not Exist**

```
Select t2.invoice_number
FROM table1 t1 Where Not Exist 
  (
   SELECT NULL 
   FROM table2 t2 
   WHERE  t2.invoice_number = t1.inovice_number
  )
```

**Try with Not IN**

```
Select t2.invoice_number 
FROM table1 t1
Where t1.inovice_number NOT IN
(
 SELECT t2.inovice_number
 FROM table2 t2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply try:

```
Select * from Table1
Where Table1.invoice_number NOT IN (select invoice_number from Table2)
```

Comment: not efficient in mysql. use `LEFT JOIN` or `NOT EXISTS()` instead.

Comment: @JohnWoo agree, your answer with `left join` would be better for performance perspective

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT t1.invoice_number 
FROM   table1 t1
       LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.invoice_number = t1.inovice_number
WHERE  t2.invoice_number IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `where not exists`?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 t2 WHERE t1.invoice_number = t2.invoice_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not the correct way to query what you are looking for.

You probably need something like this:

```
select invoice_number from table2 
where invoice_number not in (select invoice_number from table1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1 where invoice_number NOT EXISTS (select invoice_number FROM table2 WHERE  table1.invoice_number = table2.invoice_number);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t2.id FROM table1 as t1
INNER JOIN table2 as t2 ON t2.id != t1.id;
```